# How to calculate line from a set of polygon points?

Tags: algorithm, vector, polygon

Let's say now I have an array that used to describe the shape of a polygon:

```
[
  [0.0, 1.0],
  [0.5, 1.0],
  [0.5, 0.3],
  [1.0, 0.3],
  [1.0, 0.0],
  [0.0, 0.0]
]
```

[image]

As shown on diagram above, the blue line(s) or vector points list is the result I was looking for.

Assuming the polygon only composed of one or more rectangular shapes, is there any way to extract/simplify the polygon to one or more lines?

Comment: What is this line? What if your polygon has a form of cross? Are you looking for some kind of [skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton)?

Comment: Hi @Dmitry , thanks for the swift response! After doing some researches on the mentioned skeleton topic, ya I think it would be the exact solution of this problems, thanks again! :D

Comment: @Herks this may help you as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132143/how-to-compute-the-mitered-offset-of-a-polygon-using-its-straight-skeleton